# Under what circumstances will the executable first found in the path not be used

Tags: zsh, path

I am having some strange behavoir with zsh ( 5.4.2_1 installed with homebrew ) on osx not using the first occurrence of an executable in the path.

Here is the scenario:

`echo $PATH` returns:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/zplug/HEAD-9fdb388/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

**brew** is in both

```
/usr/local/Cellar/zplug/HEAD-9fdb388/bin
```

and

```
usr/local/bin/brew
```

This is confirmed by running **which -a brew** which returns:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/zplug/HEAD-9fdb388/bin/brew   
/usr/local/bin/brew
```

But when I run **which brew** it returns:

```
/usr/local/bin/brew
```

and **brew** does run `/usr/local/bin/brew` rather than `/usr/local/Cellar/zplug/HEAD-9fdb388/bin/brew`

How can this happen when brew is earlier in the path ?

Help appreciated.

Comment: `rehash` and run those again - if it still happens afterwards, [edit] that in.

Comment: @MichaelHomer: Yup that's the one. Experience here.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

`which -a cmd` looks for all regular files named `cmd` which you have execute permission for in the directories in `$path` (in addition to aliases, functions, builtins...).

While `which cmd` returns the command that `zsh` would run (`which` is a builtin in `zsh` like in `tcsh` but unlike most other shells).

`zsh`, like most other shells remembers the paths of executables in a `hash` table so as not to have to look them up in all the directories in `$path` each time you invoke them.

That hash table (exposed in the `$commands` associative array in `zsh`) can be manipulated with the `hash` command (standard POSIX shell command).

If you have run the `brew` command (or `which/type/whence brew`, or used command completion or anything that would have primed that hash/cache) before it was added to `/usr/local/Cellar/zplug/HEAD-9fdb388/bin` or before `/usr/local/Cellar/zplug/HEAD-9fdb388/bin` was added to `$path`, `zsh` would have remembered its path and stored it as `$commands[brew]=/usr/local/bin/brew`.

In that case, you can use `hash -r` (as in the Bourne shell) or `rehash` (as in csh) to have `zsh` *forget* the remembered commands (invalidate that *cache*), so it can look it up next time and find it in the new location.

Comment: Thanks - this sorted the problem. Should I be able to echo  $command[brew] - I  see nothing ?

Comment: @continuum, sorry, my bad, that's `$commands`, not `$command`. See edit.

Answer (score 0):

`/usr/local/bin/brew` is a usually a symbolic link.

So **`/usr/local/bin/brew`** and
**`/usr/local/Cellar/zplug/HEAD-9fdb388/bin/brew`**

are probably the same files.

type:

```
ls -al /usr/local/bin/brew
```

to confirm.