# binary placed in folder on $PATH is not immediately accessible

Tags: zsh, path, executable

in my `$PATH` I have folder `~/.zsh/bin` which I use for small scripts and custom built executable binaries, for example I added a recently compiled tool I made called `wercker_build_status` to the folder. Yet when I type in the command line `wercker_build_status` it can't find it, I have to type the full path to the file, `~/.zsh/bin/wercker_build_status`.

That's not to say nothing in the folder doesn't work, a script I have called `wifi_status` is in there and typing that into the command line returns the wifi status as expected.

Why is it even though it's in my `$PATH` I can't just use a file I add to the folder `~/.zsh/bin`?

Comment: I suppose it works if you open a new terminal window (or any way to spawn a new shell)?

Comment: What is your PATH? Is the tool executable? Is zsh OK with having tilde in PATH instead of $HOME?

Comment: @UlrichSchwarz it does not why does my `$PATH` matter when I explicitly stated that the folder is in the path? and yes it is executable and so far I've never had a problem with ZSH and having a tild in the PATH.

Comment: OK, so it's probably not a caching issue. (IIRC, zsh will cache the names for tab completion, I'm not sure if it does the same for searching the path.)

Comment: M. Schwarz is thinking of https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/408859/ , https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/82991/ , and many others in the same vein.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `$HOME` in your path rather than tilde (`~`), especially if you enclose the new `PATH` in double quotes.  The tilde is not expanded when it occurs in quotes.

Testing:

```
$ mkdir "$HOME/t"

$ cat >"$HOME/t/foo" <<END
#!/bin/sh
echo "hello"
END

$ chmod +x "$HOME/t/foo"

$ PATH="$PATH:~/t"

$ foo
zsh: command not found: foo

$ PATH="$PATH:$HOME/t"

$ foo
hello
```

See also: [Why doesn't the tilde (~) expand inside double quotes?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/151850/why-doesnt-the-tilde-expand-inside-double-quotes)